# Tic-Tac-Toe Game Function To Check For Winner

Tags: c

I've written the following code for a tic-tac-toe game on my own:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void instructions();
void printboard(char board[3][3]);
int wincheck(char board[3][3]);

int main(){
        char tictac[3][3] = {{'-', '-', '-'}, {'-', '-', '-'}, {'-', '-', '-'}};
        int player = 0;
        int win = 0;
        int player_choice = 0;
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;

        instructions();
        for(int i=0; i<9 && win==0; i++){
                printboard(tictac);
                player = i%2 + 1;
                do{
                        printf("\nPlayer #%d, enter your spot choice:\n", player);
                        scanf("%d", &player_choice);
                        if(player_choice == 1){
                                row = 0;
                                col = 0;
                        }
                        else if(player_choice == 2){
                                row = 0;
                                col = 1;
                        }
                        else if(player_choice == 3){
                                row = 0;
                                col = 2;
                        }
                        else if(player_choice == 4){
                                row = 1;
                                col = 0;
                        }
                        else if(player_choice == 5){
                                row = 1;
                                col = 1;
                        }
                        else if(player_choice == 6){
                                row = 1;
                                col = 2;
                        }
                        else if(player_choice == 7){
                                row = 2;
                                col = 0;
                        }
                        else if(player_choice == 8){
                                row = 2;
                                col = 1;
                        }
                        else if(player_choice == 9){
                                row = 2;
                                col = 2;
                        }
                        else{
                                printf("Not a valid choice, please choose again.");
                        }

                }while(player_choice<0 || player_choice>9 || tictac[row][col]!='-');
                if(player == 1){
                        tictac[row][col] = 'X';
                }
                else if(player == 2){
                        tictac[row][col] = 'O';
                }
                if(wincheck(tictac)!=0){
                        win = player;
                }
        }
        printboard(tictac);
        if(!win){
                printf("\n\nTHE GAME IS A DRAW!\n");
        }
        else{
                printf("\n\nCONGRATULAIONS PLAYER #%d, YOU WON!\n", win);
        }
}

void instructions(){
        printf("\n\t\t\t  WELCOME TO TIC TAC TOE!\n");
        printf("\nGame Rules:\n");
        printf("\nThe program will ask the player to enter which spot they would like to place their X or O.\nPlease use spot numbers as shown below:\n\n");
        printf("\t\t\t\t 1 | 2 | 3 \n");
        printf("\t\t\t\t---+---+---\n");
        printf("\t\t\t\t 4 | 5 | 6 \n");
        printf("\t\t\t\t---+---+---\n");
        printf("\t\t\t\t 7 | 8 | 9 \n");
        printf("\n\t------------------------LET'S BEGIN!------------------------\n\n\n");
}

void printboard(char board[3][3]){
        printf("\t\t\t\t %c | %c | %c \n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
        printf("\t\t\t\t---+---+---\n");
        printf("\t\t\t\t %c | %c | %c \n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
        printf("\t\t\t\t---+---+---\n");
        printf("\t\t\t\t %c | %c | %c \n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
}

int wincheck(char board[3][3]){
        if((board[0][0]==board[0][1] && board[0][0]==board[0][2]) || (board[1][0]==board[1][1] && board[1][0]==board[1][2]) || (board[2][0]==board[2][1] && board[2][0]==board[2][2])){
                return 1;/*Checks to see if player has won across any of the rows.*/
        }
        else if((board[0][0]==board[1][0] && board[0][0]==board[2][0]) || (board[0][1]==board[1][1] && board[0][1]==board[2][1]) || (board[0][2]==board[1][2] && board[0][2]==board[2][2])){
                return 1;/*Checks to see if player has won down any columns.*/
        }
        else if((board[0][0]==board[1][1] && board[0][0]==board[2][2]) || (board[0][2]==board[1][1] && board[0][2]==board[2][0])){
                return 1;/*Checks to see if player has won in a diagonal.*/
        }
        else{
                return 0;
        }
}
```

I'm running into an issue when trying to play the game though. After the first player chooses a "play spot" it thinks they have won already. Because of this I believe the issue is most likely due to an error in the wincheck function but I can't quite figure out what exactly is causing the issue. I'm a beginner programmer, so I apologize if this is kind of a dumb question. I really appreciate any help you can offer!

Comment: You are not checking for `-` in  `wincheck`. That is, you are incorrectly matching three adjacent `-` entries as a win.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!  I see the issue now, and I really appreciate the help!

Comment: the code could be greatly shortened/cleaned up by remembering that there are only 8 ways to win in tac-tac-toe.  so a static/const table can be defined, then the code simply loops through the table, looping though each table row, and comparing the associated locations (that table contains row/col coordinates of the game board) to see if a specific player has a matching entry at each of the game board coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is *indeed* with your `wincheck` function. It rightly checks that the three candidate cells are equal but does *not* check that those cells have been populated. That means the game will be detected as won even before a move is made (since *all* cells are set to `-`, a simple equality check will pass).

It's therefore not enough to do *just* the equality check, you also have to ensure that at least *one* of those cells has been set to a real player.

You can also make your code a bit more readable with a little refactoring, something like:

```
// Returns the actual winner, or '-' if none. Needs x/y start cell
// and x/y deltas (direction, basically).

int checkOneWinPossibility(char board[3][3], int x, int y, int xd, int yd) {
    // Check all no-winner scenarios, return winner only if they all fail.

    if (board[x][y] == '-') return '-';
    if (board[x][y] != board[x+xd][y+yd]) return '-';
    if (board[x][y] != board[x+xd*2][y+yd*2]) return '-';

    return board[x][y];
}

int checkAllWinPossibilities(char board[3][3]){
    int winner;

    // Horizontals.

    if ((winner = checkOneWinner(board, 0, 0, 0, 1)) != '-') return winner;
    if ((winner = checkOneWinner(board, 1, 0, 0, 1)) != '-') return winner;
    if ((winner = checkOneWinner(board, 2, 0, 0, 1)) != '-') return winner;

    // Verticals.

    if ((winner = checkOneWinner(board, 0, 0, 1, 0)) != '-') return winner;
    if ((winner = checkOneWinner(board, 0, 1, 1, 0)) != '-') return winner;
    if ((winner = checkOneWinner(board, 0, 2, 1, 0)) != '-') return winner;

    // Diagonals.

    if ((winner = checkOneWinner(board, 0, 0, 1, 1)) != '-') return winner;
    if ((winner = checkOneWinner(board, 2, 0, -1, 1)) != '-') return winner;

    return '-';
}
```

That last diagonal check *could* be combined with the `return` statement just by doing:

```
return checkOneWinner(board, 2, 0, -1, 1);
```

but I prefer (being slightly OCD) to leave it as is for consistency :-)

They also both return the *actual* winner rather than just an indication that there is a winner. You may not *need* that information since it will obviously be the last player that moved, but there's no probably no substantial harm in returning the extra information.